# Should I create MongoDB user manually?

Tags: mongodb, macos

1. I installed mongodb via brew, using '**brew install mongodb**'.
2. Created '**/data/db**' folder to let 'mongod' process save files there, (**sudo mkdir -p /data/db**).
3. But the process doesn't have write permissions. And I don't have any mongo-like users in '**/etc/passwd**'. Should I manually create this user, how should I call him?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `sudo mkdir -p /data/db`, you are creating that directory as root. My guess is that you are then running `mongod --dbpath /data/db` as another user, which doesn't have read, write, and execute on /data/db. The user running mongod needs access to the data directory.

Whatever user you are logged in as, you can create the directory with `mkdir -p /data/db`, then run `mongod --dbpath /data/db` as that same user, and you should be fine.

You may need to create a new OS user to do this, and you can create that user with whatever name makes sense to you.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I temporarily solved the problem following brew output instructions (after installation) about how to run mongodb.